# How to test Twitter Cards?

Tags: twitter

I am setting up Twitter Cards using a player card. It works in the preview tool, but the docs say it needs to be tested "on twitter.com modern desktop browser? Native iOs & Android Twitter app? mobile.twitter.com iOS & Android default browsers?"

How can I test it on twitter.com and twitter mobile apps if it hasn't been approved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had this same question which was unanswered on the Twitter Developer Forum. I was able to get a player card URL validated and have my domain white-listed without first reviewing in each different context.

Make sure your URL meets the Player Card requirements (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started). My twitter:player entries point to a simple html page which contains a VideoJS player, my content is defined so it resizes to 100% width and height (so that the small mobile web experiences won't experience cropping.) Of course all assets must be fetched via https like defined in the docs.

The Player Card should really help with video/channel views for those that have a large Twitter following.

Good luck,
Stan

Answer (score 8):

Twitter have added a Card Validator. Not sure if this will help you, but it might help others who land on this page from a Google search.

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: Great link ! Unfortunately for my case (https://www.marcwrobel.fr/jargon-programmation-fonctionnelle) this only tells me "Unable to render Card preview" without error or warning in the logs. So I do not known if it is because of my website or because this validator is not working anymore.

Comment: FYI: Sometime after Musk’s takeover, the validator became defunct.